# How can I open a page with only one django model object's info after clicking it's ImageField on another page?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am displaying django models on one of my website's pages. When I press one's ImageField on the page, I want it to open another page including only that one object. How do I do that ?
I thought about using the filter method in my views.py for filtering through my objects and finding that exact one, but I don't know what arguments to use.
Any ideas? (I am a beginner in django)

**VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from . import models

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')


def new_search(request):         ********NOT IMPORTANT (I THINK)********
    search = request.POST.get('search')
    models.Search.objects.create(search=search)
    objects = models.Object.objects.all()
    results = objects.filter(name__contains=search).all()
    args = { 'results': results }

    return render(request, "my_app/new_search.html", args)


def individual_page(request):
    link = request.GET.get('object-link')
    objects = models.Object.objects.all()
    return render(request, "my_app/individual_page.html")
```

**MY TEMPLATE**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% load static %}

    <h2 style="text-align: center">{{ search | title }}</h2>
    <div class="row">
        {% for result in results %}
                <div class="col s4">
                    <div class="card medium">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <a name="object-link" href="{% url 'individual_page' %}"><img src="{{ result.image.url }}" alt=""></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <p>{{result.name}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-action">
                            <a href="/">View listing: Price TEST</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

So, the thing I want to do is: when I press the anchor tag that includes the image, I get redirectioned to another page which contains only that one object's info.

Comment: first you could add parameter to URL which you get in view and use it to filter data from database and get only one result. it can be ID of row in database.

Comment: yes, you create urls like `/individual_page?id=ID` and then you can use  `id = request.GET.get('id')` to get this `ID` and use it in model `.get(id)` (instead of `.all()`) OR you can use `/individual_page/ID` and then you would have to change route to somethng like `/individual_page/<int:id>` and probably use `def individual_page(request, id):`

Comment: thank you very much sir, it works fine (I used the second method). there is still a minor problem which I will most likely be able to fix myself

Comment: if you use second method then probably you could use `{% url 'individual_page' id=result.id %}` to generate url - but I'm not sure if it was in `Django` or `Flask`